# Android tablet freezes on connecting to Mac - OS X

Tags: android, macos, adb, tablet

I have a bit specific problem. I am developing an Android app for tablets and one device that got into my hands freezes every time i connect it to my mac and running ADB. It works, when i don't have running adb. 
When i try to connect i receive this error

```
MacBook-Pro-2:~ user$ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
adb E 65548 3480511 usb_osx.cpp:302] Could not clear pipe stall both ends: e0004051
adb E 65548 3480511 usb_osx.cpp:284] Could not find device interface
* daemon started successfully *
```

This is where it freezes.

It doesn't happen on other devices. This device is clearly Chinese one and our firm will use it as Kiosk. It has also Ethernet port and many more. When i connect it through wifi for debugging it works, but i am curious, where might be the problem. It's somehow improved Allwinner A20. In Android studio it shows me name Unknown SoftwinerEvb.

And one more thing. It perfectly works on Windows.

If you have any clue, where might be the problem, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any answer for this, same problem on gotab

Answer (score 1):

A hard reboot (power Off/On) to the Hardware did the trick for me. Or, even toggling the developer options works.